# Is this possible to show the custom userprofile property in user info list without populating values to the property?

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-information-list, userprofiles, userprofile-sync

I have created two custom userprofile property  , I marked it as replicable to show that property in user info list. My custom property is showing in user information list after when that property have values and profile sync. I am not sure  whether this is default. Is this possible to show the properties in user information list without populating the values?

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually run the profile synchronization jobs by running the stsadm sync command:

```
stsadm –o sync
```

If the information is not synced, try using the following stsadm sync command which will only delete the sync info using PowerShell, then start SharePoint Full Synchronization job again:

```
stsadm –o sync –listolddatabases <x number of days>
stsadm –o sync –deleteolddatabases <x number of days>
```

The first command will list Content Databases that have not been synchronized since n days.

The second command will delete the records corresponding to those databases. It doesn't delete databases/end user data.